# How to run formula(s) through all possible permutations in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, permutation

So I have a matrix containing data for orders coming in that looks like this:

```
Order   Due Date    Processing Time   Early Penalty   Late Penalty
 1        4              5                2               8
 2        7             10                4               7 
 3        5              1                8               9
 4        5              3                7               2
 ..      ...             ...              ..              .. 
 ..      ...             ...              ..             .. .
```

I am trying to perform a Job Shop Sequencing algorithm on these orders to minimize penalty by comparing due date and processing time to one another. How do I run the formula(s) through all possible permutations of the orders?

For instance, I would like to apply a particular formula on each sequence of orders. 
(sequence 1: order 1 -> order 2 -> order 3 -> order 4, sequence 2: order 2 -> order 4 -> order 3 -> order 1, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The function `perms` will help you to do this. `perms` lists all of the permutations of a vector, so for instance:

perms(1:4)

ans =

```
 4     3     2     1
 4     3     1     2
 4     2     3     1
 4     2     1     3
 % Cut 16 rows
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     4     3
 1     4     2     3
 1     4     3     2
```

Be warned, however, that this will become unmanageable very quickly. The number of permutations of a list grows with the factorial of the length of the list. So with 4 orders, you have 24 permutations. With 10 orders, you've now got 3628800 permutations. With 15 orders, you've got 1.3077e+12 permutations (that's 1.3 trillion). If you can guarantee that the number of orders will never get above about 10, then this method should still work.